# Adding more menu in the menu settings?

Tags: routes

In Drupal 7, in admin/structure/menu/settings we have the main links and the secondary links.

Can we add third one here? Is there any way to get the list of all menus created in backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we add third one here?

Yes, we can. Use [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), alter form_id [`menu_configure`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--menu--menu.admin.inc/function/menu_configure/7).

How do I know what form_id? Let's see `menu_menu()` at `http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--menu--menu.module/function/menu_menu/7`

> Is there any way to get the list of
>   all menus created in backend?

Again, We can. Select menus in table {menu_links} where {menu_links}.menu_name = management.

```
    $result = db_select('menu_links', 'm')
    ->fields('m')
    ->condition('menu_name', 'management','=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();
```

Comment: Should i use hook_form_Alter in theme-settings.php or template.php?

Comment: http://pastie.org/1966956 this is not working

Comment: I found out we are not able to do it in theme we can do it from a module though.

Answer (score 0):

On the "Menus" menu, you can select "Add new Menu" in the upper part of the window. Once added, you can go to "Blocks" to select where that new menu will be.

Also on "Menus" you can see all menus in your site (Main, Navigation and user-created)